# Grouping and sorting XSLT by key and position()

Tags: xml, xslt, key, grouping, xslt-2.0

I am trying to display data sorted alphabetically so that items that begin with the same letter are in separate columns. These columns can hold a maximum of 10 items before a new column is started. I can successfully divide the data up alphabetically AND divide it up by number of items per column but I am struggling to combine the 2:

Divided alphabetically:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:key name="node-by-first-letter" match="node" use="substring(@email, 1, 1)" />


<div class="scroller-panel">
    <xsl:for-each select="msxml:node-set($members)/node[count(. | key('node-by-first-letter', substring(@email, 1, 1))[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="@email" order="ascending"/>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="group" />
</xsl:for-each></div></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node" mode="group">
    <div class="column-312 scroller-item people-search-column fade-panel">
    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="Exslt.ExsltStrings:uppercase(substring(@email,1,1))"/>
    </h2>
    <ul class="stripe-list">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('node-by-first-letter', substring(@email, 1, 1))" mode="item">
            <xsl:sort select="@email" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>    
    </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node" mode="item">
            <li>
                <a href="4.0.1.person.profile.html">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@email"/>
                </a>
            </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Divided by max items per column:

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxml:node-set($members)/members/member[position() mod 10 = 1]">
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::*[not(position()    >=   10)]">
<li>
<xsl:value-of select="@email"/>
</li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Preferred output is like:

http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/9676500/9676792_3580_625x625.jpg

Comment: Provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: Why not mixing both solutions using a multi-pass transform?

Comment: Excellent question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that demonstrates Several techniques: 1) Muenchian grouping based on the starting character of a value; 2) Positional grouping of items that are not siblings (and may be from different documents and not elements at all).

Comment: I also added detailed explanation.

Comment: @empo: In XSLT 1.0 a multi-pass transformation typically requires the use of the `xxx:node-set()` extension function to convert the result of a previous step from RTF to a regular tree. My solution doesn't require any extension functions.

Comment: I also added a much shorter and easier XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: And also added explanation of the XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 5):

**I. XSLT 2.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pColLength" as="xs:integer" select="10"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <names>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="name"
                           group-by="substring(.,1,1)">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()"
          group-by="(position()-1) idiv $pColLength">
          <column>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </column>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </names>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (as no such was provided in the question!!!):

```
<names>
        <name>T A</name>
        <name>T B</name>
        <name>T C</name>
        <name>T D</name>
        <name>T E</name>
        <name>T F</name>
        <name>T G</name>
        <name>T H</name>
        <name>T I</name>
        <name>T J</name>
        <name>T K</name>
        <name>T L</name>
        <name>A A</name>
        <name>A B</name>
        <name>A C</name>
        <name>A D</name>
        <name>A E</name>
        <name>A F</name>
        <name>A G</name>
        <name>A H</name>
        <name>A I</name>
        <name>A J</name>
        <name>A K</name>
        <name>A L</name>
        <name>X A</name>
        <name>X B</name>
        <name>X C</name>
        <name>X D</name>
        <name>X E</name>
        <name>X F</name>
        <name>X G</name>
        <name>X H</name>
        <name>X I</name>
        <name>X J</name>
        <name>X K</name>
        <name>X L</name>
        <name>R A</name>
        <name>R B</name>
        <name>R C</name>
        <name>R D</name>
        <name>R E</name>
        <name>R F</name>
        <name>R G</name>
        <name>R H</name>
        <name>R I</name>
        <name>R J</name>
        <name>R K</name>
        <name>R L</name>
</names>
```

**produces the desired output -- names sorted by starting first letter and put into columns of 10 items each**:

```
<names>
   <column>
      <name>A A</name>
      <name>A B</name>
      <name>A C</name>
      <name>A D</name>
      <name>A E</name>
      <name>A F</name>
      <name>A G</name>
      <name>A H</name>
      <name>A I</name>
      <name>A J</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>A K</name>
      <name>A L</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>R A</name>
      <name>R B</name>
      <name>R C</name>
      <name>R D</name>
      <name>R E</name>
      <name>R F</name>
      <name>R G</name>
      <name>R H</name>
      <name>R I</name>
      <name>R J</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>R K</name>
      <name>R L</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>T A</name>
      <name>T B</name>
      <name>T C</name>
      <name>T D</name>
      <name>T E</name>
      <name>T F</name>
      <name>T G</name>
      <name>T H</name>
      <name>T I</name>
      <name>T J</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>T K</name>
      <name>T L</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>X A</name>
      <name>X B</name>
      <name>X C</name>
      <name>X D</name>
      <name>X E</name>
      <name>X F</name>
      <name>X G</name>
      <name>X H</name>
      <name>X I</name>
      <name>X J</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>X K</name>
      <name>X L</name>
   </column>
</names>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Nested [`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)** -- first grouped by the starting character, then for each such determined and sorted group --  by the number of the column in which its items should be.
2. **Use of the standard XSLT 2.0 functions [`current-grouping-key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-grouping-key) and [`current-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-group)**.

**II.XSLT 1.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pColLength" select="10"/>

 <xsl:key name="kStarting" match="name"
  use="substring(.,1,1)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <names>
          <xsl:for-each select=
           "name
              [generate-id()
              =
               generate-id(key('kStarting', substring(.,1,1))[1])
              ]
           ">
            <xsl:sort select="substring(.,1,1)"/>

            <xsl:variable name="vgroupNames" select=
               "key('kStarting', substring(.,1,1))"/>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vgroupNames[1]">
              <xsl:with-param name="pGroup" select="$vgroupNames"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pGroupLength" select=
               "count($vgroupNames)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:for-each>
  </names>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
   <xsl:param name="pGroup"/>
   <xsl:param name="pGroupLength"/>
   <xsl:param name="pInd" select="1"/>

   <xsl:if test="not($pInd > $pGroupLength)">
      <column>
       <xsl:copy-of select=
       "$pGroup
           [position() >= $pInd
          and
            not(position() > $pInd + $pColLength -1)
            ]"/>
      </column>

      <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "$pGroup[position() = $pInd + $pColLength]">
       <xsl:with-param name="pGroup" select="$pGroup"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pGroupLength" select="$pGroupLength"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pInd" select="$pInd + $pColLength"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document** (as above), **the same desired output is produced -- names sorted by starting first letter and put into columns of 10 items each**:

```
<names>
   <column>
      <name>A A</name>
      <name>A B</name>
      <name>A C</name>
      <name>A D</name>
      <name>A E</name>
      <name>A F</name>
      <name>A G</name>
      <name>A H</name>
      <name>A I</name>
      <name>A J</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>A K</name>
      <name>A L</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>R A</name>
      <name>R B</name>
      <name>R C</name>
      <name>R D</name>
      <name>R E</name>
      <name>R F</name>
      <name>R G</name>
      <name>R H</name>
      <name>R I</name>
      <name>R J</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>R K</name>
      <name>R L</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>T A</name>
      <name>T B</name>
      <name>T C</name>
      <name>T D</name>
      <name>T E</name>
      <name>T F</name>
      <name>T G</name>
      <name>T H</name>
      <name>T I</name>
      <name>T J</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>T K</name>
      <name>T L</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>X A</name>
      <name>X B</name>
      <name>X C</name>
      <name>X D</name>
      <name>X E</name>
      <name>X F</name>
      <name>X G</name>
      <name>X H</name>
      <name>X I</name>
      <name>X J</name>
   </column>
   <column>
      <name>X K</name>
      <name>X L</name>
   </column>
</names>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Using the [Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml)**, plus sorting, we obtain (in sorted order)  each group of `name` elements consisting of all names starting with the same character.
2. **Every group of `name` elements as obtained above is processed by applying templates to its first `name` element**. The whole group, its length and the index of the `name` element in the group (default = 1) are passed as parameters.
3. **The template matching a `name` element is guaranteed to be applied only on a starting element within a column**. It creates a new `column` element and copies in it all `name` elements for this column (starting from index `$pInd` and ending at index `$pInd+$pColLength -1`. There is no requirement that these elements should be siblings (and they aren't). If not just copying but also additional processing is required for each `name`, this can be done here by replacing the `<xsl:copy-of>` instruction with:

-

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="process" select=
           "$pGroup
               [position() >= $pInd
              and
                not(position() > $pInd + $pColLength -1)
                ]"/>
```

Comment: +1 for good answer(s). I suggested `node-set()` because starting from OP information I was not able to give a full solution (input missing), and did not think about creating one myself as you correctly did. This is the right approach indeed.

Comment: @empo: What one can learn from this answer is that it isn't necessary for nodes to be siblings in order to group them into columns.