# XSLT split result in groups of 3

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

An web-application is providing me an XML-feed, which I can't change. What I want to do is split this XML-feed into several unordered lists. I'm trying to do this with the XSLT below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >    
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:param name="html-content-type" />
  <xsl:template match="/NavigationTree">
    <xsl:if test="count(//Page) > 0">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//Page">    
    <li class="{position() mod 3}">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[»&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          <xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
      </a>
    </li>

    <xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 0">
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; count(//Page)">
        <!--Don't know if this is the correct approach, but when the position is 3 and there are more items following
        I want to create an new unordered list-->
      </xsl:if>      
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the XSLT above i'm able to turn the XML into an unordered list with 6 items in it (let's assume there always are 6 items). Similar to the example below;

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
</ul>
```

The example above is the result i'm getting at the moment. But the desired result is something like this;

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT - Sample XML input

```
<NavigationTree>
    <Settings>
        <!--Snipped data-->
    </Settings>
    <Page ID="5" AreaID="1" MenuText="Bestellen" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=5" FriendlyHref="/nl-nl/klantenservice/bestellen.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True"/>
    <Page ID="6" AreaID="1" MenuText="Betalen" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=6" FriendlyHref="/nl-nl/klantenservice/betalen.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="2" LastInLevel="False" InPath="True" ChildCount="0" class="L2_Active" Active="True" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True"/>
    <Page ID="7" AreaID="1" MenuText="Retourneren" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=7" FriendlyHref="/nl-nl/klantenservice/retourneren.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="3" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True"/>
    <Page ID="8" AreaID="1" MenuText="Garantie" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=8" FriendlyHref="/nl-nl/klantenservice/garantie.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="4" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True"/>
    <Page ID="9" AreaID="1" MenuText="Faq" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=9" FriendlyHref="/nl-nl/klantenservice/veel-gestelde-vragen.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="5" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True"/>
    <Page ID="10" AreaID="1" MenuText="Contact" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=10" FriendlyHref="/nl-nl/klantenservice/contact.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" ShowInLegend="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="6" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True"/>
</NavigationTree>
```

As you can see I always want output in groups of 3 items. Is this kind of html output possible using XSLT? If yes, how can I do this? Any help is welcome!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two solutions: an XSLT 1.0 solution that doesn't use any conditional XSLT instruction; and a much shorter XSLT 2.0 solution using `<xsl:for-each-group>`. For a more generic XSLT 1.0 positional grouping solution that groups a set of nodes that are *not* siblings, see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299594/grouping-and-sorting-xslt-by-key-and-position/7302747#7302747

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this, you need to match on the **Page** element that it is position 1, 4, 7, etc... In other words, where there **position() mod 3** equals 1.

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 1">
```

This gives the first element of the list. You can then get the remaining 2 elements in the this, like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::Page[position() &lt; 3]" mode="list"/>
```

Putting this altogether, gives the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
   <xsl:param name="html-content-type"/>
   <xsl:param name="group-size" select="3"/>
   <xsl:template match="/NavigationTree">
      <xsl:if test="count(//Page) &gt; 0">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Page"/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Page">
      <xsl:if test="position() mod $group-size = 1">
         <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::Page[position() &lt; $group-size]" mode="list"/>
         </ul>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Page" mode="list">
      <li class="{position()}">
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[»&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
         <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
               <xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
         </a>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your input XML, this should generate the following output

```
<ul>
  <li class="1">»&nbsp;<a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/bestellen.aspx">Bestellen</a></li>
  <li class="2">»&nbsp;<a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/betalen.aspx">Betalen</a></li>
  <li class="3">»&nbsp;<a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/retourneren.aspx">Retourneren</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="1">»&nbsp;<a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/garantie.aspx">Garantie</a></li>
  <li class="2">»&nbsp;<a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/veel-gestelde-vragen.aspx">Faq</a></li>
   <li class="3">»&nbsp;<a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Do note I have parameterised the group size, allowing you to easily change to 4 or 5 elements per list, for example.

Comment: +1 Great solution. Like the solution with the parameterised group size. Good for flexibility! Thanks for the quick and good solution:)

Comment: Actually, I have an unnecessary **xsl:if** in my solution! The test on **position() mod $group-size = 1** needs to go on the initial **xsl:apply-templates select="Page"**. I believe this would be more efficient.

Answer (score 12):

**I. XSLT 1.0**
.

**Here is a short and parameterized solution** showing how to split siblings elements in groups of predefined size. *No* explicit conditional XSLT instructions are used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pGroupSize" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <nums>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "num[position() mod $pGroupSize = 1]"/>
  </nums>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <group>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    ".|following-sibling::*
              [not(position() > $pGroupSize -1)]"/>
  </group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<nums>
   <group>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>10</num>
   </group>
</nums>
```

**II. XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pGroupSize" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <nums>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="*"
            group-by="(position() -1) idiv $pGroupSize">
         <group>
          <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
         </group>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </nums>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<nums>
   <group>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>10</num>
   </group>
</nums>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of `<xsl:for-each-group>` where the selected nodes are grouped by the sequential number of the group they belong to.
2. Use of the standard XSLT 2.0 function `current-group()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/NavigationTree">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Page[position() mod 3 = 1]" mode="ul"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Page" mode="li">
        <li class="{position() mod 3}">
            <a href="{@FriendlyHref}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Page" mode="ul">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::Page[position() &lt; 3]" mode="li"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
  <li class="1">
    <a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/bestellen.aspx">Bestellen</a>
  </li>
  <li class="2">
    <a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/betalen.aspx">Betalen</a>
  </li>
  <li class="0">
    <a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/retourneren.aspx">Retourneren</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="1">
    <a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/garantie.aspx">Garantie</a>
  </li>
  <li class="2">
    <a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/veel-gestelde-vragen.aspx">Faq</a>
  </li>
  <li class="0">
    <a href="/nl-nl/klantenservice/contact.aspx">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 good working solution. But i prefer the one from Tim C due to more flexibility when I want to change the number of items shown.