# Diazo rules split content in columns

Tags: css, plone, diazo

I have to split my page content in columns with diazo rules, how can I do this?

from something like this

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="item1">content1</div>
    <div id="item2">content2</div>
    <div id="item3">content3</div>
    <div id="item4">content4</div>
    <div id="item5">content5</div>
    <div id="item6">content6</div>
    <div id="item7">content7</div>
    <div id="item8">content8</div>
    <div id="item9">content9</div>
</div>
```

to something like this

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3" id="item1">content1</div>
        <div class="span3" id="item2">content2</div>
        <div class="span3" id="item3">content3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="span3" id="item4">content4</div>
        <div class="span3" id="item5">content5</div>
        <div class="span3" id="item6">content6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">           
        <div class="span3" id="item7">content7</div>
        <div class="span3" id="item8">content8</div>
        <div class="span3" id="item8">content8</div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably not always 9 items? Always three items per row? Always three items per column? I suppose you _have_ to use the row structure so looking at flexbox doesn't help you?

Comment: of course end this is only a little sample, but I have to use diazo rules to do this on a Plone portal

Comment: @robystar why the css-tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use something like the following:

```xml
<xsl:template match="div[@id='content']/div[position() mod 3 = 1]">
  <div class="row">
        <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::div[position() &lt; 3]">
              <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="div[@id='content']/div[position() mod 3 != 1]">
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand where I was wrong, now it works

Comment: @robystar Remember that plone encloses the content in an `id="content"` and this can under some circumstances conflict with your `id="content"` is you use it in a content view which is embeded in other views.

Answer (score 1):

Code your theme file exactly as in "to something like". Rules to pull your content:

```
<rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">
    <replace css:theme-children="#item1" css:content-children="#item1" />
    <replace css:theme-children="#item2" css:content-children="#item2" />
    <replace css:theme-children="#item3" css:content-children="#item3" />
    ... you get the idea
</rules>
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I want a dynamic solution, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316260/xslt-split-result-in-groups-of-3. I haven't a fixed layout in my theme

Comment: So, trying to break a consecutive set of divs into rows of three?

Comment: exactly, I corrected my code as suggested by wolfrevo and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your application supports css3, then try multiple columns.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp