# xml paged transposed transaction sorted data display as html table in xslt2

Tags: xml, xslt

Got same old (unordered) xml data file (7 "records" this time) ...

```
<trnsctns>  
 <trnsctn date="19/01/01"><OB>180</OB><amnt/></trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="19/03/03"><OB/><amnt>33</amnt></trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="19/02/02"><OB/><amnt>21</amnt></trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="19/05/05"><OB/><amnt>29</amnt></trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="19/04/04"><OB/><amnt>44</amnt></trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="19/06/08"><OB/><amnt>17</amnt></trnsctn> 
<trnsctn date="19/07/03"><OB/><amnt>17</amnt></trnsctn>
</trnsctns>
```

and through Martin Honnen's xslt2/xslt3 transform stylesheet ([xml transposed transaction sorted data display as html table in xslt2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77815976/xml-transposed-transaction-sorted-data-display-as-html-table-in-xslt2)) was able to bulk sort display ALL that xml data file.

Very good think and I thank him again for this valuable solution.

On one hand all this (mentioned) data is supposed to be displayed over some mobile device (mobile phone) and on the other hand all that data stuff grows so one need a **pagination** mechanism in order display it. Really sorry for keep coming with this, but really think that's the last time I'd need this sort of requirment.

Anyway this paged and sorted xml data transformed (xslt2/xslt3) display I need it exactly as showcased through the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2twnxz97/7/

Meaning that over that previously xslt transform one should "only" add that pagination system. This would be it.

Looking forward on this pagination technique which was unable to figure  out how could be done.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: The shown jsfiddle obviously does the pagination with JavaScript in the browser. If that is your aim, why don't you add that script to the result document of the XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your script in the result document of the XSLT, e.g. from the previous answer you would add a template creating the HTML and including the script with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head xsl:expand-text="no">
      <title>Example pagination</title>
      <script><![CDATA[
onload=function()  
    {
    colsPerPage=3 
    currentPage=1
    table=document.getElementById('myTable')  

    totalCols = table.rows[0].cells.length - 1 // Exclude the header row
    // calculate the total number of pages
  totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCols/colsPerPage)

    // Initialize the pagination container
    paginationContainer=document.getElementById('pagination-container')

    // Initial display of the first page
  displayPage(1)
 }

// Function to display the specified page
function displayPage(pageNumber)
{
 startIndex=(pageNumber-1)*colsPerPage + 1
 endIndex=Math.min(startIndex+colsPerPage-1,totalCols)

 for(i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++)
  for(j=1;j<=totalCols;j++)
   table.rows[i].cells[j].style.display=(j>=startIndex && j <= endIndex)?'':'none'
   
 currentPage=pageNumber
 updatePagination()
}

function updatePagination() // update pagination controls
{
 const paginationLinks=generatePaginationLinks()
 paginationContainer.innerHTML=''
 paginationContainer.appendChild(paginationLinks)
}

function generatePaginationLinks()
{
 fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
 createLink = function(text,clickHandler)
        {
         link=document.createElement('a')
         link.href = '#'
         link.textContent = text
         link.addEventListener('click',function(event)
            {
             event.preventDefault()
         clickHandler()
            })
         return link
         }

 first = createLink('|<First',function()
            {
             displayPage(1)
            })
 fragment.appendChild(first)
 previous = createLink('<Previous',function()
             {
              if(currentPage>1)
               displayPage(currentPage-1)
             })
 fragment.appendChild(previous)

 pageInfo = document.createElement('span')
 pageInfo.id = 'pgnInf' 
 pageInfo.textContent = `${currentPage}/${totalPages}`
 fragment.appendChild(pageInfo)

 next = createLink('Next>',function()
             {
              if(currentPage<totalPages)
               displayPage(currentPage + 1)
             })
 fragment.appendChild(next)

 last=createLink('Last>|',function()
              {
        displayPage(totalPages)
              })
 fragment.appendChild(last)
 return fragment
}        
      ]]></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

then adjust the template outputting the table to ensure it has the id attribute and it also adds that `span` for your pagination/navigation:

```
<xsl:template match="/trnsctns">
    <xsl:variable name="data-table">
      <tr>
          <th>date</th>
          <th>ob</th>
          <th>amnt</th>
          <th>cb</th>
      </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="process">
            <xsl:with-param name="transactions" as="element()*" select="trnsctn => sort((), function($t) { replace($t/@date, '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})', '$3$2$1')})"/>
        </xsl:call-template>          
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:variable name="swapped-table" select="mf:swap-table($data-table/tr)"/>

    <table id="myTable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>crrntNmbr</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($swapped-table[1]/*) - 1">
          <td>{position()}</td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:sequence select="$swapped-table"/>
    </table>
    
    <span id="pagination-container"></span>

</xsl:template>
```

You only need to add your CSS for the layout of the table and the navigation/pagination area and you should get the result you want.

Comment: Thank you very much mr. Honnen. I'll certainly give it a go .. 
Then I'll be back with a reply.
 Thank you again on your this fast reply. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes. Now really got your point. Actually everything could also be done as the xslt transform had already that html table generated.
But, you know, when saying "ain't being able figuring out some xsl pagination technique" really was refering over something like in post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75202860/xml-nodes-limit-display/77888356#77888356
where all the limit displaying (x recs/page) was done through xslt, and those links actually reloaded the page, but everytime with next page or previous one; and so on and so forth.
 Maybe you could help me with this sort of technique ..?

Comment: Another point extremely important. For basically all the SaxonJS transfom are actually async happening, there is some important add over the js script:
onload=async function(){
try { 
 await SaxonJS.transform(opts,"sync")    
 dsplPage(1) 
 }
catch(err)
  { 
   console.error("Error :", err)
  }
}
function dsplPage(pagNmbr)
{
 table=document.getElementById('dtaTbl') 
 totalCols = table.rows[0].cells.length - 1 // Exclude the header row
 totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCols/colsPerPag) 
 strtIdx=(pagNmbr-1)*colsPerPag + 1 
 endIdx=Math.min(strtIdx + colsPerPag-1,totalCols)
...
}

Comment: @mirexS, I am not sure what you want to tell me or others with that comment but your question didn't not mention SaxonJS at all, it was tagged as xslt and xml and then asked to achieve some pagination already spelled out as a JavaScript fiddle. Feel free to add your own answer with some more detailed and specialized code if you also edit the question and mention exactly in which environment you are looking for a solution.